# Commutative ring with unity problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I cannot tackle the problem.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let $a$, $b$, $c\in R$ be such that there exists $x$, $y$, $z\in R$ with $$xa+yb+zc=1.$$ Show that there exist $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma\in R$ such that $$\alpha a^{15}
> +\beta b^{16}+\gamma c^{17}=1.$$

Can anyone give a hint how to 
start? Actually I was thinking about binomial expansion. Will it be helpful or any other way would be better?

Comment: Seems like a cool question. However you should write it in LaTeX code in the actual question to make it more convenient for everyone. Also you will get community disapproval because your question does describe what you've tried so far. Personally I don't agree with the validity of this disapproval, but in any even, you'll still get it. Feel free to include a description of what you've done so far if you care to avoid it.

Comment: Please **at least** copy the statement of the problem. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for some tips on asking good questions. A good start is to put effort in the asking!

Comment: Actually I cant use latex and I regret that.

Comment: The meta site has an intro to mathjax somewhere. It's not hard. Learn it. Without it most users won't read your question because they don't want to click on a linked image.

Comment: This website is a great place to learn basic LaTeX. Just look up an online getting started guide and you'll be right.

Comment: Ok i will learn it surely

Comment: I inserted the pic. Do learn TeX enough to typeset this, comes in handy later! Ok, Mariano did it this time, but the recommendation still stands.

Comment: Hint: If you raise the given equation to fourth power, and expand the left hand side, then each term will have at least one of $a^2$, $b^2$, $c^2$ as a factor for otherwise the total exponent $i+j+k$ of $a^ib^jc^k$ would be at most $1+1+1=3<4$. Binomial expansion? Almost! You need trinomials here (but it amounts to much the same thing).

Comment: Can it be done without binomial expansion. I mean to say by using ideal @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: There is a corresponding fact involving coprime ideals. But, IIRC, in the texts I've seen the analogue of this result is proven at the level of elements exactly the way I hinted at. Mind you, I'm not very knowledgeable about commutative algebra so others may be able to suggest alternative routes.